# How can I read remote text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I habe a text file at \192.168.18.141\SnortLogs\alert_json.txt. I have shared it using samba and I can access it through my windows machine. I have to write code in javascript to read the contents of text file.

Comment: You'll need a library or some kind of proxy if you want to read it over `smb://`.  Browsers really only let client JS make HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

try this but you must be have the permission

```
var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
        var theFileContent = fr.result;
        //add your code here
    }
    fr.readAsText("192.168.18.141\SnortLogs\alert_json.txt");
```